# Error [NSISLinearExpression orientationChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I got this error in app when i change orientations, i got it first time in life, i have never seen this type of error before,

i have searched lot regarding this error but i found nothing to solve this,

in my app i have write NSNotification for orientation change

**Scroller.m**

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        scrollView=[UIScrollView new];
        pageControl=[UIPageControl new];
        scrollView.delegate=self;

        scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
       scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;


        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [self addSubview:scrollView];
        [self addSubview:pageControl];
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
        [self setData];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)orientationChanged{
 [self updateFrame];

}
-(void)updateFrame{

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    CGRect mainFrame=scrollView.frame;
    CGRect frame;
.
.
.
.
    // COdes for Updating Frame
}
```

But i am getting this error:

**`-[NSISLinearExpression orientationChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9477c0
2014-02-28 09:56:04.919 TKScroller[604:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSISLinearExpression orientationChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa9477c0'`**

**Edit:**

I have remove parameter in observer and method, and
After  Running it i got new error

**`[__NSArrayM orientationChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0845f0
2014-02-28 10:27:40.202 Scroller[810:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM orientationChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0845f0'`**

**SOLVED**

I have remove observer in dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Comment: Did you Google for it???  You sent an orientationChanged: message to an NSISLinearExpression object, and that class does not have a method by that name!!

Comment: @HotLicks: yes i have searched in google `[NSISLinearExpression orientationChanged:]` but i didnt find anything thats why i have put question here.

Comment: i have edited question, please check .

Comment: You didn't search for "unrecognized selector".

Comment: In case it's not clear, NSArray doesn't implement `orientationChanged:` either.  Show us a stack trace!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After so many tries i found that i have not removed observer, so i have remove it in dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```